# Filter a list of paths in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a file ("dump_file") containing a list of paths (generated from a `hadoop fs -ls` output), formatted this way :

```
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1/dir2
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1/dir2/dir3
- abcdef 1201 2021-06-01-13:15 /dir1/dir2/dir3/file1
- abcdef 78441 2021-06-01-13:16 /dir1/dir2/dir3/file2
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1/dir2/dir4
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1/dir2/dir4/dir5
- abcdef 1201 2021-06-01-13:15 /dir1/dir2/dir4/file11
- abcdef 78441 2021-06-01-13:16 /dir1/dir2/dir4/file22
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 /dir1/dir6/dir7
```

My goal is to extract 1st level children of any given node.
So far this is what I got (example with "dir1") :

```sh
grep -Eio "/dir1.[^\/]+" < dump_file | sort -u | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'
```

```
dir2
dir6
```

But I'd like to have also the first fields of the matching lines, like this :

```
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir2
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir6
```

"dir1/dir2" as value should return :

```
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir3
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir4
```

"dir1/dir2/dir4 :

```
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir5
- abcdef 1201 2021-06-01-13:15 file11
- abcdef 78441 2021-06-01-13:16 file22
```

Do you have an idea of how I can do this ? Thanks !

Comment: If you provide `dir1` as input, isn't the output supposed to be `dir2,  dir6`?

Comment: You're right, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Pass value of string which you want to look for in your Input_file inside value variable of this `awk` program.

```
awk -v value="dir1" '
BEGIN{ len=length(value) }
match($0,"/"value"/[^/]*"){
  matVal=substr($0,RSTART+len+2,RLENGTH-len-2)
  if(!arr[matVal]++){
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) matVal
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v value="dir1" '          ##Starting awk program from here, setting value to string which we want to look for.
BEGIN{ len=length(value) }     ##Creating len which has length of value here in BEGIN section.
match($0,"/"value"/[^/]*"){    ##Using match function to match given string along with next level of it here.
  matVal=substr($0,RSTART+len+2,RLENGTH-len-2) ##Creating matVal which has matched value sub string here.
  if(!arr[matVal]++){          ##Checking condition if value already does not exist in array then do following.
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) matVal  ##printing rest of line and matched value(only directory level) here.
  }
}
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

***EDIT:*** With OP's samples of passing `dir1/dir2` OR `dir1` OR `dir1/dir2/dir3` and as per comments to ignore paths such as `foo/dir1/dir2` where passed value is in sub directory mode then one could try following, beware this will fail if your path contains regexp metachars(I will try to fix it in sometime, if I could).

```
awk -v value="dir1/dir2" '
BEGIN{ len=length(value) }
match($0,"[[:space:]]+/"value"/[^/]*"){
  matVal=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",matVal)
  sub("^/"value"/","",matVal)
  if(!arr[matVal]++){
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) OFS matVal
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I must admit that it will take me some time to fully understand it, but it's perfectly working ! Thanks !

Comment: @Joulss, your welcome. I have added detailed explanation for code, in case of any queries feel free to comment here, cheers

Comment: Actually I also have to be able to handle limit and offset on results (multipaged results). I initially planned to do it with grep, but there's no grep anymore...

Comment: @Joulss, awk is a great and more capable language comparison to grep, cheers and keep posting Good Q & A on this forum.

Comment: That would fail if the target directory name contained regexp metachars like `.` since you're using it as part of a regexp in `match()`, and it'd fail if the target highest level directory name appeared as a subdirectory of some other highest level directory, e.g. `/foo/dir1/bar`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Ed morton is right about the two issues (regex operators and duplicates). But your solution is a lot faster than his solution (and the paths files I have to parse are huge). Do you think it would be possible to fix the problems while keeping the good performance ?

Comment: @Joulss, I have added EDIT solution which will take care of ED sir's shown sample of `foo/dir1/dir2` it wouldn't pick it. For regexp characters problem I had added a fair warning in it, I need to think of the solution covering that part, will get back here if I could come up with any new approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it seems to fix the duplicates issues and the regex metachars one (at least when the dir name contains a dot)

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = $0
    sub("[[:space:]]+/.*","",head)
    sub("[^/]+","")
}
index($0,"/" tgt "/") == 1 {
    $0 = substr($0,length(tgt) + 3)
    sub("/.*","")
    if ( !seen[$0]++ ) {
        print head, $0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='dir1' -f tst.awk file
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir2
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir5
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='dir1/dir2' -f tst.awk file
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir3
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir4
```

---

Original answer assuming you only wanted to specify the head dir, not a path, as the target:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = $0
    sub("[[:space:]]+/.*","",head)
    sub("[^/]+","")
    nd = split($0,dirs,"/")
}
(nd>2) && (dirs[2] == tgt) && !seen[dirs[3]]++ {
    print head, dirs[3]
}
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='dir1' -f tst.awk file
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir2
d hdfs 0 2021-06-01-13:14 dir5
```

The above assumes none of your target directory names contain escape sequences like `\n`.

Comment: You're right about issues with directories names containing regex metachars.
I tried your script, it seems to work only on the first level (test with `dir1/dir2` returns nothing), and it doesn't list files (maybe I was not clear about that in the question)

Comment: Right, it's designed to work with a target first directory name like `dir1` as shown in your question. If you have some other use case not mentioned there then please edit your question to clarify your requirements and include an example showing that. If you want to be able to specify a multi-directory path as the target that's trivial to handle, it just doesn't look like what you want in  your question.

Comment: `dir1` was an example but I mentioned that `My goal is to extract 1st level children of a given node`. Maybe it was unclear but I didn't said that the given node is supposed to be 1st level only. Anyway I will edit my question, thanks.

Comment: The new solution works fine, thanks. There's performance issues on big files, but I will try to improve it.

Comment: The main problem, I think, is the word `node` - it could mean `directory` or it could mean `path` or something else. I'm shocked to hear there's a performance issue on any size of file.

Comment: I ran a test that returns 1021 results from a 437037 lines file. Your script run in `4.486` seconds while Ravinder's one run in `0.482` second.

Comment: Let's assume those are 3rd-run timings so not just reflecting cache-ing impact on timing. You're comparing a solution that will work for all directory names and runs in 4 secs to another that will fail for some directory names but runs in 0.4 secs (I see in his updated script Ravinder fixed one issue but introduced another). You can choose whichever solution best suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -sl

$re = qr[^((?:\S+\s+){4})/\Q$dir\E/([^/]+)];
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print $1.$2 if m[$re]o and !$seen{$2}++;
}
```

```
perl above.pl -dir=dir1/dir2 file
```

This is based on a perl regex using two capture groups – one to catch the first four fields, and another to catch the portion after "/dir1/dir2/". `\Q...\E` is used to escape any regex metacharacters.

The same regex can be used with `pcregrep` (+`sort -u` to remove duplicates):

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 '^((?:\S+\s+){4})/dir1/dir2/([^/]+)' file | sort -uk5
```